# Apache2 can't access using public ip

Tags: php, apache2, vtiger, vtigercrm

Hi I have an Apache web server in ubuntu 18.04.02 when I try to access my site (VTiger CRM 7.1) using my public IP it always redirects to my private IP

Current conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin admin@example.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/crm/
     ServerName example.com 
     ServerAlias www.example.com

     <Directory /var/www/html/crm/>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Firewall disabled

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your CRM is configured to work on the external IP? maybe it is redirecting you upon your first visit.

Comment: config.inc.php
config.template.php
config.php <- customer portal

all set to public ip i didn't notice that thank you

But i have another problem i can't login to the customer portal now

Error : Cannot connect to Server.Please configure your site url in provided config file.

Comment: Looks like it wants a full URL, not just IP Address.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Pretty much as the error says, you need a full domain in the config.php instead of IP address. For example http://example.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use the following $site_URL in config.inc.php and replace that with current value

```
$site_URL = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS']==='on' ? 'https': 'http')."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) != '/' && dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) != '\\' ? str_replace('\\','/',dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) : '').'/';
```